# Can't stop dialogue box with ExecWB 4, 2

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking to save the HTML of a web page using Excel VBA. Using `ExecWB 4, 2` works great except for the confirmation dialogue box. I cannot turn this off despite 2 meaning `OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER` :(

I've searched long and hard for the solution with no luck.

Also – sendkeys does not work since the program won't leave the ExecWB line until the dialogue box is closed. `URLDownloadToFile` does not work either.

Here's the code:

```
Sub rmaster()    
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    With IE
            .Visible = False
            .Navigate "http://www.google.com"            
            Do While IE.ReadyState <> 4
                DoEvents
            Loop
    End With

    IE.ExecWB 4, 2, pages & ".txt"
    IE.ExecWB 4, 2, pages & ".htm"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` before the line at which prompt occurs?

Make sure you turn it back on after the concerned lines with : `Application.DisplayAlerts = True`

Comment: I don't think this is solvable.  Msft support > The WebBrowser control and Internet Explorer have Save and Save As options that can be used to save files using the ExecWB command. However, this involves prompting from the user. There is no way to suppress this prompt. To save files to the hard-disk without prompting, use the URLDownloadToFile API from URLMON. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/244757